# More efficient use of an XMLReader

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xmlreader

I have the following code:

```
    for (i = 1; i <= loopsNeeded; i++)
    {
        lblCurrent.Text = string.Format("{0} of {1}", i, loopsNeeded);
        prgWriteProgress.Value = i;
        this.Refresh();

        reader = XmlReader.Create(FilePath);
        outputFile = CreateXmlOutputFileName(xmlFileInfo);
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
        xslArg.AddParam("Index", "", currentNode);
        xslArg.AddParam("BatchSize", "", batchSize);

        transformation.Transform(reader, xslArg, stream);

        currentNode+=batchSize;

        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
    }
```

This code runs through an XML file picking out a certain batch of information each time and it progressively moves through the file.

According to MSDN:

> XmlReader provides forward-only, read-only access to a stream of XML data.

This gives me the issue of needing to re-define the XML reader each loop to ensure it starts at the top of the file.

Tests gave the following feedback:

```
125,000 information nodes/125,000 per batch file = 48 mins.  
125,000 information nodes/5000 per batch file = 58 mins.  
125,000 information nodes/500 per batch file = 2 hours 33 mins.
```

As you can see there is a heavy repercussion when running smaller batch sizes due to the requirement to constantly reload an 0.8gig file into the XMLReader.

Is there a way to avoid having to redeclare the XMLReader each time, thus reducing the overhead I encounter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). It provides a far nicer abstraction of a Xml Document.

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);
for (i = 0; i < loopsNeeded; i++)
{
  ...  
  var reader = xDocument.CreateReader();
  ...
}
```

Comment: And you can then create a reader from the document in order to do the transform.

Comment: Shall look into this now and get back to you.

Comment: But at 800MB it's not trivial. Better run with 64 bits

Comment: This took 40 seconds off the 5000 batch test, will run the 500 batch tomorrow as this is where it will be most noticeable, not got the time to run it before i go home tonight :)

Comment: Took 4 minutes off the longer process, not too much but better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but would it be better in this case to instead do something like (pseudo code, sorry):

```
Load the xmlreader

loop through the nodes that you want to match from in the reader

    if node matches criteria
         output node

end loop
```

Means you load the reader once, but retain the fast, forward only nature of the reader for your large document.

Comment: As I match different criteria in each loop of the cycle I have to put the XML reader back to the start position by re-assigning it. That is where I lose the performance. - unless I misunderstand you?

Comment: For this to work you would need to make 'set' of the criteria you want to match and match a node to see if it exists in your set of criteria - you don't loop through the criteria.

Comment: It depends on your requirements - if you're only matching a couple of nodes, then your first way may be better - if you're matching a high percentage of the nodes, then this way may be better.

Comment: I can match any number of nodes in one loop, could be the entire file, could be one node per file, its a variable that the end user can control. Currently peformance testing @rich.okelly's answer and will see from there whether i'll look into this one of not.